# jquery autocomplete suggestions hidden

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-autocomplete, frameset

When using jquery autocomplete in a frameset, the list of suggestions is hidden behind the lower frame. 
When using a usual Html select field - values are shown on top of the lower frame (as should be).[Html select - OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRRV3.png)
[jquery autocomplete - hidden - not OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBGyN.png)

Working with framesets is enforced in this project by the framwork... nothing we can do about that.

Comment: Please upload the relevant code to the question or create [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) of the problem - It will help you get answers instead of getting your question closed/downvoted (But as a hint - I will search where to add a hight `z-index` to the list)

Comment: Doesn't it help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104073/how-make-jquery-ui-autocomplete-get-out-iframe ?!

Comment: @AlonEitan `z-index` works on document, iframe has its own document context, different than the parent page's one

Comment: @A.Wolff Thanks for clarify it. I didn't notice it was an Iframe, that's why I asked for the code. That make Mavreick answer correct then

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest two things mate,

a) Increase the Height of your Frame, say may be atleast 200px

b) Set the following css in the same page as autocomplete:

```
<style>
       .ui-autocomplete {
            max-height: 150px;
            overflow-y: auto;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            padding-right: 20px;
        } 
</style>
```

Hope this helps !!